# If $B$ is invertible, Is $B^{1/2}$ invertible? with $B\geq 0$

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be a complex Hilbert space. Let $B\in \mathcal{L}(E)^+$ (i.e. $\langle Bx\;, \;x\rangle\geq0$ for all $x\in E$).

> If $B$ is invertible i.e. $B$ is bijective and $B^{-1}\in \mathcal{L}(E)$. Is $B^{1/2}$ invertible?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $A=B^{1/2}$. Then $A^2=B$.
Then what about $C=AB^{-1}$? Obviously $AC=A^2B^{-1}=I$. Does $CA=I$
also?